# Can't execute firefox in root account

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, firefox

I using the Xubuntu 14.04 and I can't execute some program(gedit,firefox...) except terminal and FileManger in Root account,but I can execute it in Guest account.

Here is log,when execute firefox in root account.

---

```
(firefox:8729): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox: symbol lookup error:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: cairo_surface_set_device_scale
```

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run FireFox as root as always without password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/618091/run-firefox-as-root-as-always-without-password)

Comment: You should not run a browser as root.

Answer (score 1):

It is **dangerous** and therefore not recommended to run **firefox** with root permissions, because it makes your computer easier to attack via the internet.

If you want to run **gedit** and other tools with root permissions you should *not use plain sudo, because it can damage configuration files* in your home directory. Instead you should use

```
sudo -H gedit
```

or if the package `gksu` is installed

```
gksudo gedit
```

or use command line tools like the following editors: the simple `nano` or advanced but more difficult `vim`

```
sudo nano filename

sudo vim filename
```

Comment: hello sudodus,Thank you for suggestion,I just input command line "firefox" to execute and get the  error in log ,I want to know how to fix it

Comment: Does firefox work for you when started by the regular user (not root)? Or from the menu?